Fortify で確認パスワードを無効にする方法は？
Laravel Fortifyを使用してログイン機能を導入しました。
Laravel Framework 8.83.8
PHP 7.4.9
確認パスワードが不要なので消したいのですが、どのファイルを触れば良いのかわかりません。
コードは教材のものなので、確認パスワードをフォーム記入する状態のものとなっています。
register.blade.php
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('css')
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/register.css') }}">
@endsection

@section('content')
<div class="register__content">
    <div class="register-form__heading">
        <h2>会員登録</h2>
    </div>
    <form class="form" action="/register" method="post">
        @csrf
        <div class="form__group">
            <div class="form__group-title">
                <span class="form__label--item">お名前</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form__group-content">
                <div class="form__input--text">
                    <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" />
                </div>
                <div class="form__error">
                    @error('name')
                    {{ $message }}
                    @enderror
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form__group">
            <div class="form__group-title">
                <span class="form__label--item">メールアドレス</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form__group-content">
                <div class="form__input--text">
                    <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" />
                </div>
                <div class="form__error">
                    @error('email')
                    {{ $message }}
                    @enderror
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form__group">
            <div class="form__group-title">
                <span class="form__label--item">パスワード</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form__group-content">
                <div class="form__input--text">
                    <input type="password" name="password" />
                </div>
                <div class="form__error">
                    @error('password')
                    {{ $message }}
                    @enderror
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form__group">
            <div class="form__group-title">
                <span class="form__label--item">確認用パスワード</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form__group-content">
                <div class="form__input--text">
                    <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form__button">
            <button class="form__button-submit" type="submit">登録</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="login__link">
        <a class="login__button-submit" href="/login">ログインの方はこちら</a>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection


自身で解決にたどり着きましたので記載しておきます。
passwordRulesの 'confirmed' を削除することで確認パスワードを無効にすることができました。
VSCode内でキーワード検索することで道が切り開けました。
この投稿でどなたかの手助けになればと思います。
ありがとうございました。
対象ファイル:
src/app/Actions/Fortify/PasswordValidationRules.php
<?php

namespace App\Actions\Fortify;

use Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Password;

trait PasswordValidationRules
{
    /**
     * Get the validation rules used to validate passwords.
     *
     * @return array<int, \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule|array|string>
     */
    protected function passwordRules(): array
    {
        return ['required', 'string', Password::default(), 'confirmed'];
    }
}

